# Unable to run f2c program

Tags: command-line, scripts, filesystem

After the installation of f2c, it is required to have this following file:

```
/usr/local/bin/f2c
/usr/local/include/f2c.h
/usr/local/lib/libf2c.a
/usr/local/man/man1/f2c.1t
/usr/local/bin/f77
```

1. How to check the existence of the file?
2. In order to translate, compile, link, and run a program, I need to run `f2c hello.f` but, I receive `Cannot open hello.f: No such file or directory`. How to find the file/directory of hello.f?

Comment: First question 'check existence of file' I don't understand, `file` is a command which I don't believe you mean, so what specific file do you mean?.  Second question `hello.f` must be in your current directory ($PWD); commands are searched for in $PATH (/usr/local/bin/ is usually in there) so `f2c` will be found, but what directory are you in, and is `hello.f` in that directory?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, it is a typo. In the terminal, it is f2c hello.f and it doesnt work.

Comment: @guiverc what I mean is in the /usr/local/, I can't find the /bin/f2c, /include/f2c.h, /lib/libf2c.h, /man/man1/f2c.1t and /bin/f77. For the second question, I am in the user directory and I am not sure where and how to find f2c. it isnt in /usr/local/bin/ .

Comment: The f2c program gets installed into /usr/bin, not /usr/local/bin.  Did you install the libf2c2-dev for the include file(s)?  Probably you need the libf2c2 package also.

Comment: @ubfan1 I do have the libf2c2-dev as well. Thank you, you are right. it is installed in /usr/bin.